# Errors when looping through spatial join with python

Tags: arcpy, typeerror

I am attempting to loop through a list of inputs and create a spatial join for each.  My code works as desired for the first object in the list, but then throws an error.  Here is my code:

```
# set local variables
env.workspace = "mydatabase"
input_location = "myinput"

input_features = ["Element Point", "Element Line", "Element Polygon",
"Community or Other Point", "Community or Other Polygon"]
output_features = ["element_point", "element_line", "element_poly", "community_point",
"community_poly"]
county = "countylayer"

for input, output in zip(input_features, output_features):
    target_features = os.path.join(input_location, input)
    join_features = os.path.join(env.workspace, county)
    output_features = os.path.join(env.workspace, output)

    # create a new fieldmappings and add the two input feature classes as objects
    fieldmappings = arcpy.FieldMappings()
    fieldmappings.addTable(target_features)
    fieldmappings.addTable(join_features)

    # first gets COUNTY_NAM fieldmap which is a field in the counties feature class
    # the output will have the elements with the names of the counties
    county = fieldmappings.findFieldMapIndex("COUNTY_NAM")
    fieldmap = fieldmappings.getFieldMap(county)

    # get the output field's properties as a field object
    field = fieldmap.outputField

    # rename the field and pass the updated field object back into the field map
    field.name = "county"
    field.aliasName = "county"
    fieldmap.outputField = field

    # set the merge rule to first and then replace the old fieldmap in the mappings
    # object with the updated one
    fieldmap.mergeRule = "first"
    fieldmappings.replaceFieldMap(county, fieldmap)

    for field in fieldmappings.fields:
        if field.name not in ["county", "refcode","dm_stat", "last_up_by", "last_up_on"]:
            fieldmappings.removeFieldMap(fieldmappings.findFieldMapIndex(field.name))

    # run the spatial join tool, using the defaults for the join operation and join
    # type
    arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(target_features, join_features, output_features, "#",
    "#", fieldmappings)
```

And here are the errors I am getting after it successfully completes the first spatial join:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 24, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\ntpath.py", line 67, in join
    p_drive, p_path = splitdrive(p)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\ntpath.py", line 115, in splitdrive
    if len(p) > 1:
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Answer (score 2):

If the first run works but the second run fails, the first thing to check would be to make sure you're not trying to create a new dataset where one already exists.

Also, you've defined `output_location` at the top of the script but aren't using it anywhere. Perhaps you need to change the `output_features` assignment in your loop?

> output_features = os.path.join(**output_location**, output)

Comment: To be sure there weren't any existing datasets, I used a completely empty file geodatabase.  I deleted the out_location definition because, indeed, I did not use it and did not mean to use it.  After these updates, I am still getting the same error message.

Comment: The error says `object of type 'int' has no len()` which makes me think you've got a column defined as integer with null values. You'll need to replace nulls with a zero.